# How Can solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I try to run main.dart in USB device (Nokia 3.1 Plus) I have this in the Debug Console : 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 769
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm64'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

flutter doctor shows any problem

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 769
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm64'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1